# Where can I find the implementation of "time.h"?

Tags: c

Where can I find the implementation of time.h in the C Standard Library, i.e `time.c`?

I tried with Google Code Search [time.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&filter=0&q=time.c++lang:c&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:c) 
Is the implementation in the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`time.h` is a header from the C standard library.

You will find implementations of the various functions this header provides in the c library implementation of your system.
For instance, the implementation for the `difftime` function in the `libc` used for [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org) can be found in [src/lib/libc/time/difftime.c](http://nxr.netbsd.org/xref/src/lib/libc/time/difftime.c).

Answer (score 4):

For GNU libc, see http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=time;h=c950c5d4dd90541e8f3c7e1649fcde4aead989bb;hb=master

Answer (score 1):

You can find an implementation in the GNU libc library. There isn't a single time.c file. Each function (to a first approximation) lives in its own compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually looking for the implementation of C in the standard library?
Each compiler and OS typically comes with their own implementation (just the headers are relatively standard).

You can see instructions on downloading the sources for GNU C here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/resources.html

Answer (score 0):

`time.h` is a C standard header, so it describes functions from the C standard library with which it came. For instance, GNU `libc`