# Where can I download the source code for the functions declared in stdlib.h?

Tags: c, open-source, standard-library

Where can I download the source code of the latest or standard library for stdlib.h? I would like to see how are those functions are implemented, such as atoi, strtol, etc?

Comment: You can search for things like "atoi source" on google to find implementations.

Comment: http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629455/where-i-can-find-implementation-of-time-h-c-standard-library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion would be that you check out the GNU C Library source code for this.  You can download it here: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/

Comment: Hopefully not a dead link in the near future: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=stdlib;h=b47e85702e144a94a7c2291b458979a230f93d7e;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

That is in the libc, such as glibc, dietlibc, etc. Check your OS to see which libc it uses, and where (if) you can download its source.