# Where is time.h implementation code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I have found the `time.h` header file on Ubuntu, but where is the actual source file containing the implemented functions defined in the header? I cannot seem to find it? Is the file named `time.cpp`, or `time.c`?

Thanks.

Comment: It's part of the C runtime library, on Linux systems typically glibc. And if you download the source package, the functionality is not in a single file, it's spread out in multiple files.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because my Eclipse isn't recognising CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID in the syntax checker and I wanted to actually try and see where this variable is declared??

Comment: @user997112 run `grep -r CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID  /usr/include/` It'll be in some file that time.h includes, probably via a handful of indirections. Also keep in mind that Eclipse could use a lot of improvement in the way it figures out C/C++ symbols

Comment: `clock_gettime()` et al, including `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, are POSIX.1-2001 functionality. To get them declared, you need to `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L` (or later; POSIX.1-2008 is `200809L`) before including `time.h`. `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is actually a preprocessor macro, defined to the value `2` in `/usr/include/linux/time.h`, `/usr/include/bits/time.h`, and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h`, on Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS on x86-64.

Answer (score 5):

The header only contains the function prototypes, which only declares the function. Then it links with your C library, which is precompiled for you by Ubuntu. Your C library is probably `glibc`, standing for the GNU C Library, and you can find the sources for it on the [GNU website](http://gnu.org/software/libc). Be forewarned, however, that the implementation is highly optimized, and you may be better off reading the documentation. The time implementation, including `time.c`, can be found [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=time;), on GitWeb.

Answer (score 0):

This in general has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629455/where-can-i-find-the-implementation-of-time-h).
I assume the syntax checker warns in your source, and not when opening time.h. If so, the CLOCK_xxx identifier should be defined in time.h, so no implementation required for the IDE. Might be that you have an older libc, which does not yet define it, so just check your time.h.